# Flutter - Push and Get value between routes

Tags: dart, flutter

How do I send the green string from the HomePage page to the ContaPage page?

I think it's so `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/conta/green');` but I do not know how to get in the page `conta` the `green` string

So, by getting the value of the string I can for example change the color of the backgroundColor of `appBar` in `ContaPage`.

**main.dart**

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: "MyApp",
      home: new HomePage(),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
        '/home': (BuildContext context) => new HomePage(),
        '/conta': (BuildContext context) => new ContaPage()
      },
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      backgroundColor: new Color(0xFF26C6DA),
    ),
    body: new ListView  (
      children: <Widget>[
        new FlatButton(
          child: new Text("ok"),
          textColor: new Color(0xFF66BB6A),               
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/conta');
          },
        ),
      ],
    )
  );
}

class ContaPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      backgroundColor: new Color(0xFF26C6DA),
    ), 
  );
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can create a `MaterialPageRoute` on demand and pass the argument to the `ContaPage` constructor.

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: "MyApp",
      home: new HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      backgroundColor: new Color(0xFF26C6DA),
    ),
    body: new ListView  (
      children: <Widget>[
        new FlatButton(
          child: new Text("ok"),
          textColor: new Color(0xFF66BB6A),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => new ContaPage(new Color(0xFF66BB6A)),
            ));
          },
        ),
      ],
    )
  );
}

class ContaPage extends StatelessWidget {
  ContaPage(this.color);
  final Color color;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      backgroundColor: color,
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Is the process the same if it is `popAndPushNamed`?

Comment: Just call `Navigator.pop(context)` and then `Navigator.push(context, ...)`. It does the same thing.

Answer (score 7):

A better solution is already given on Flutter website, how to use:

**Arguments**

```
class ScreenArguments {
  final String title;
  final String message;

  ScreenArguments(this.title, this.message);
}
```

**Extract arguments**

```
class ExtractArgumentsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/extractArguments';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ScreenArguments args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(args.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(args.message),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Register Route**

```
MaterialApp(
  //...
  routes: {
    ExtractArgumentsScreen.routeName: (context) => ExtractArgumentsScreen(),
    //...
  },     
);
```

**Navigate**

```
Navigator.pushNamed(
      context,
      ExtractArgumentsScreen.routeName,
      arguments: ScreenArguments(
        'Extract Arguments Screen',
        'This message is extracted in the build method.',
      ),
    );
```

> Code copied from [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments).

Comment: This is the only solution it worked for me. The examples I saw in the flutter page involved the use of `onGeneratedRoute`, but that event was never called in my case when pushing the named route.

Answer (score 6):

You could always make a static variable String with green as it's value in your HomePage and use that value in your routes when you are creating a new ContaPage. Something like this:

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: "MyApp",
      home: new HomePage(),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
        '/home': (BuildContext context) => new HomePage(),
        '/conta': (BuildContext context) => new ContaPage(HomePage.color)
      },
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  static String color = "green";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      backgroundColor: new Color(0xFF26C6DA),
    ),
    body: new ListView  (
      children: <Widget>[
        new FlatButton(
          child: new Text("ok"),
          textColor: new Color(0xFF66BB6A),               
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/conta');
          },
        ),
      ],
    )
  );
}

class ContaPage extends StatelessWidget {

  ContaPage({this.color})
  String color;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      backgroundColor: new Color(0xFF26C6DA),
    ), 
  );
}
```

There is probably better solutions but this popped into my head first :)

Comment: But if I have 3 `FlatButton` each one sends a color, how do I step each color specified by the push?

Comment: The onPressed method would look like this:
onPressed: () {
  color = "myNewColor"
  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/conta');
},

Comment: You simply change the color in the onPressed function before you navigate.

Comment: Surely you can't change the color as its static?

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit late, but it might help some one. I think the best way is to use flutter route project [fluro](https://github.com/theyakka/fluro).

define some where globally:

```
final router = Router();
```

after that define the routes

```
var contaHandler = Handler(handlerFunc: (BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> params) {
  return ContaPage(color: params["color"][0]);
});

void defineRoutes(Router router) {
  router.define("/conta/:color", handler: contaHandler);
}
```

set the `onGenerateRoute` in `MaterialApp` to use the router generator:

```
 new MaterialApp (
   ...
   nGenerateRoute: router.generator
   ...
 ),
```

you have to add the fluro in the dependencies :

```
 dependencies:
     fluro: "^1.3.4"
```

and do the package upgrade by the following or the IDE way.

```
 flutter packages upgrade
```

Comment: What if I'm having json Object then how can I send ?? I'm trying this navigateTo(context, '/detail_screen/$propertyObj',
              transition: TransitionType.native); but having no luck. Its giving error on NextScreen.

Comment: @AnujSharma, try `json.encode` and `json.decode`. Actually what I mean is to send the json as a string.

Comment: @AnujSharma you can try https://stackoverflow.com/a/55325051/7784230 if it is not solved yet.

Answer (score 2):

**Passing data from 1st Page to 2nd**

In 1st page

```
// sending "Foo" from 1st page
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Page2("Foo")));
```

In 2nd page.

```
class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  final String string;
  Page2(this.string); // receiving "Foo" in 2nd
}
```

---

**Passing data back from 2nd Page back to 1st**

In 2nd page

```
// sending "Bar" from 2nd
Navigator.pop(context, "Bar");
```

In 1st page, it is the same which was used earlier but with little modification.

```
// receiving "Bar" in 1st
String received = await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Page2("Foo")));
```