# How to pass JSON response to another view

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and start developing my first app in flutter but facing issue in routing data from one dart file to another. The example of my code is given below.

I have define route in main.dart like this

```
final routes = <String, WidgetBuilder>{
    Login.tag: (context) => new Login(),
    HomeView.tag: (context) => new HomeView(),
  };
```

I have two separate file for login and homeview

In Login file the tag is also defined and as the user authenticate it will navigate to HomeView.

```
// tag defination
static String tag = 'login';


//Navigate on successfull login
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(HomeView.tag);
```

So, How can I pass the userdata in that navigator command to HomeView that was fetch using REST Api in JSON format.

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49445888/8097803

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass non-string data to a named route in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47419908/how-do-i-pass-non-string-data-to-a-named-route-in-flutter)

Comment: This answer may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/44729625.

I am using the fluro package for routing purpose and I am able to pass the Json data as a string as well. 
Please let me know if you requires a sample with the same

Comment: @ShyjuM Please can you provide me the sample code that will be a great help for me to understand how to use it.

Answer (score 4):

I am using the package [fluro](https://github.com/goposse/fluro) for routing purpose in my flutter app. We can pass JSON data from one screen to another as explained below

Add the dependency

```
dev_dependencies:
  fluro: ^1.2.1
```

Define a router

```
Router router = new Router();
```

Define the route, where 'data' is your Json string to be passed

```
router.define('home/:data', handler: new Handler(
      handlerFunc: (BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> params) {
        return new Home(params['data'][0]);
      }));
```

Navigate as below

```
var bodyJson = '{"buyerId":1281,"orgId":3041}';
router.navigateTo(context, '/home/$bodyJson');
```

You can receive the Json string in your Home screen.

Sample project is available [here](https://github.com/shyjuzz/flutter-samples/tree/master/flurosample)

Comment: Hi, 
I tested it and working fine but when i sent a dynamic JSON data to it. It just sent me a null response. I also print the response is console but it is not null. Can you explain me how can I achieve it.

Comment: try this way (without fluro) : Navigator.push(
              context,
              new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new SecondScreen('Data to be passed')),
            );

Comment: Passing data as JSON string might break if it contains `?`.

Answer (score 0):

@MuhammadIkhlas Shyju's solution should work fine. You get null because you passed in an object instance. Convert your object to string first. Like so:

```
var bodyJson = json.encode(yourObject.toJson())
router.navigateTo(context, '/home/$bodyJson')
```