# How to pass object or list of objects in the Fluro or Flutter route navigator?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have used [Fluro](https://github.com/theyakka/fluro) package inside my Flutter app, and I implemented all of my routes with a handler like the example of this package.
Could you please let me know what is the correct way to pass an object or list of objects between routes?

Comment: you can convert the list to JSON string and pass it, refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49773862/2863386

Comment: @ShyjuMadathil Thanks for your response, I am testing your solution, I will notify you as soon as I see any results

Comment: What I dont like about @ShyjuM approach is that you have an overhead of encoding and decoding json strings. Not sure why it seems to be the only way

Comment: @MauricioPastorini Also, do so might break in the case when converted json has slash(`/`)

Comment: @ErfanJazebNikoo If you found any reliable solution, please post an answer.

Comment: @ChiragMittal I think I found a reliable solution. Posted the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to pass the data as an encoded JSON and String format like all other solutions in this question. Recently, the [Fluro](https://pub.dev/packages/fluro) plugin provides a way of pass arguments as a class object between the routes like a Flutter navigator.

After pushing a route with a custom `RouteSettings` you can use the `BuildContext.settings` extension to extract the settings. Typically this would be done in `Handler.handlerFunc` so you can pass `RouteSettings.arguments` to your screen widgets.

```dart
/// Push a route with custom RouteSettings if you don't want to use path params
FluroRouter.appRouter.navigateTo(
  context,
  'home',
  routeSettings: RouteSettings(
    arguments: MyArgumentsDataClass('foo!'),
  ),
);

/// Extract the arguments using [BuildContext.settings.arguments] or [BuildContext.arguments] for short
var homeHandler = Handler(
  handlerFunc: (context, params) {
    final args = context.settings.arguments as MyArgumentsDataClass;

    return HomeComponent(args);
  },
);
```

In the case of **using the Flutter navigator instead of the Fluro plugin** use this [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments#1-define-the-arguments-you-need-to-pass) or check the following approach.

The [Navigator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html) provides the ability to navigate to a named route from any part of an app using a common identifier. In some cases, you might also need to pass arguments to a named route. For example, you might wish to navigate to the `/user` route and pass information about the user to that route.

To pass different pieces of data, create a class that stores this information.

```dart
// You can pass any object to the arguments parameter.
// In this example, create a class that contains a customizable
// title and message.
class ScreenArguments {
  final String title;
  final String message;

  ScreenArguments(this.title, this.message);
}
```

Now you need to define a handler using [ModalRoute](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ModalRoute-class.html):

```dart
static Handler _screenHandler = Handler(
    handlerFunc: (BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> params) {
      final ScreenArguments args = ModalRoute
          .of(context)
          .settings
          .arguments;
      return PassArgumentsScreen(args?.title);
    });
```

And navigate with:

```dart
Navigator.pushNamed(
      context,
      "/screen",
      arguments: ScreenArguments(
        'Class Arguments Screen',
        'This message is extracted in the build method.',
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do that via [ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments)

so if you have object:

```
class ScreenArguments {
  final String title;
  ScreenArguments(this.title);
}
```

navigate with:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/screen", arguments: ScreenArguments("Title"));
```

and in handler:

```
static Handler _screenHandler = Handler(handlerFunc: (BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> params) {
    final ScreenArguments args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    return PassArgumentsScreen(args?.title);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution presented at [How to pass JSON response to another view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49731289/how-to-pass-json-response-to-another-view/49773862#49773862) works unless your object has a string (or the decoded JSON contains) a `/` as @Chirag said.

I'm giving my solution as it worked, since my object has an URL inside.

#### Given the router:

```
_router.define("/groups/:group", handler: Handler(handlerFunc: (context, params) {
  String param = params["group"][0];
  GroupAPIModel group = GroupAPIModel.fromJson(decodeJsonDataForFluro(param));
  return GroupDetailsScreen(group);
}));
```

#### Defining:

```
String encodeJsonDataForFluro(Map<String, dynamic> mapToEncode) {
  return jsonEncode(mapToEncode).replaceAll("/", HtmlEscape().convert("/"));
} 

Map<String, dynamic> decodeJsonDataForFluro(String encodedMap) {
  return jsonDecode(encodedMap.replaceAll(HtmlEscape().convert("/"), "/"));
}
```

### This method would reach that route:

```
void _onGroupClicked(GroupAPIModel group) {
  String bodyJson = encodeJsonDataForFluro(group.toJson());
  router.navigateTo(context: context, path: "/groups/$bodyJson");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just struggled with this and found a solution. You can do this:

```
Object object = <Your Object>
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/page/" + object.id.toString(),
        arguments: object);
```

And then access the custom object in Fluro like this:

```
  static void setupRouter() {
    router.define("page/:pageId", handler: _pageHandler);
  }

  static Handler _pageHandler =
      Handler(handlerFunc: (BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> params) {
    Object object = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    return Widget(object);
  });
```

While Fluro doesn't have this, this is a solution that isn't completely terrible.